# Executing a timeout prior to the defined delay

Tags: javascript, timeout

Say I have the following JavaScript code (in global context):

```
var t = setTimeout(f, a); // f is an arbitrary function, a an arbitrary timeout
```

One can now cancel the set timeout:

```
clearTimeout(t);
```

But is it also possible to execute the timeout prior to it normally firing?

E.g.:

```
var func = getFunctionFromTimeout(t); // Does a function like this exists?
clearTimeout(t);
func();
```

or

```
executeAndClearTimeout(t); // Does this one?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think such a function exists... but you're allready saving `t`, why not save `f` as well?

Comment: That idea is actually so simple it never crossed my mind... Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

On the server side, node.js setTimeout provides more of a object than an id.  This is undocumented territory, I think.

Of course, using these internals might be hazardous in the sense that they could change as node develops.

```
node
> function x(){ console.log("hello"); }
> z = setTimeout(x,100000)
{ _idleTimeout: 100000,
  _onTimeout: [Function: x],
  _idlePrev: 
   { repeat: 100,
     _idleNext: [Circular],
     _idlePrev: [Circular],
     callback: [Function] },
  _idleNext: 
   { repeat: 100,
     _idleNext: [Circular],
     _idlePrev: [Circular],
     callback: [Function] },
  _idleStart: Thu, 18 Aug 2011 11:11:48 GMT }
>
```

looks like you could just save z._onTimeout, clear the Timeout, and call _onTimeout  --- but as I said, might break some day.

Also, nodeJS timeouts dont always fire when they should, but can be aligned to your CPUHZ grid.... if you are running linux with 100hz, you get 10ms resolution.  I've seen them fire either early or late, in comparison with timers provided by hrtime.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but as you said it's very risky messing with private fields/methods in that they are probably not cross-browser compatible and likely to break in the future. The accuracy problem isn't one since it isn't important exactly when it fires, but more that it fires somewhere between setting the timeout and a few seconds thereafter (by default it set to 500 msec)

Answer (score 0):

No, that'ns ot possible.

However, you could write a wrapper for `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout` to achieve such a behaviour.